# Libreoffice macro to get information about document statistics

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

The problem is that the script instantly parses all the computational data from the document (if the document is large), without giving time for it to load and counting. What can be done?

```
Sub GetStatistics(cFile)
    cUrl = ConvertToURL(cFile)
    oDoc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(cUrl, "_blank", 0, Array())
    Data = oDoc.GetDocumentProperties().DocumentStatistics
    s = ""
    For i = LBound(oData) To UBound(oData)
        s = s & oData(i).Name & " : " & oData(i).Value & CHR$(10)
    Next
    MsgBox(s)
End Sub
```

[Large document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1ifm.jpg)

[Simple document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A837B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can just add e.g.

```
Wait 2000
```

after

```
oDoc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(cUrl, "_blank", 0, Array())
```

to ensure the complete loading.

To my knowledge there is no way to exactly trigger `loadComponentFromURL` has finished.